# Workflow for users to advance-add things to a table

Tags: interface-design, workflow, design-principles, user-experience, tables

Attached is a quick sketch of a table idea I’m trying to improve. Ignore the naming conventions.

Above the table are dropdowns to select an apple or an orange. The user also has the option to add a percentage to the oranges.

Oranges are sub-categories of the different apples. In my sketch, let’s say that Mandarins and Clementines are always under Granny Smith apples (and that will never change). These 2 types of oranges also cannot be listed under any other apple category.

Easily, to add to the table, the user can select an apple and then select from the list of oranges corresponding to that apple, followed by inputting a percentage.

However, I also want to allow the user to select from the oranges, input a percentage, and have the system be smart enough to connect the chosen orange to its corresponding apple category (when adding to the table).

Assume that the list of oranges is super long (like 100+ types that exist)... So I plan to add an autocomplete to the selection of oranges.

Is there a better way to do this than to keep these existing drop downs and add an autocomplete to the orange drop down?

[image]

Comment: For starters, I wouldn't use Apples and Oranges... They are nothing alike and very hard to compare, no matter what kind of table you use. :)

Comment: Why not have the orange drop down only show the options that pertain to the selected apple? Or do all choices in the orange menu apply to all items in the apple menu?

Comment: Clever! And that’s how it’ll work if an apple is selected. However, I want to offer the user 2 options. Case 1 is your comment above. Case 2 is if an apple isn’t selected and the user knows an orange they want to add. Let’s say the user wants to add a specific type of mandarin but he/she doesn’t remember the full name. Having an autocomplete will at least allow him/her to type in “mandarin” and select from a list of mandarins. Adding that will just append to the table and connect it to its corresponding apple. Hopefully that makes sense!